# scala.swing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, scala-swing

I have a very simple project that consists of a `.scala` file, a `build.sbt` file, and a `/lib` folder with a single `.jar` in it. My scalaVersion is set to 2.10.5 (for backwards compatibility) and I ran `sbt compile`, and sbt downloads .jars for scala-2.10 and scala-swing. So it seems like that part is working...

When I do `sbt run` I get a runtime error:

```
[info] Running GuiProgramOne 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableLike$class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableLike$class
    at scala.swing.RefSet.<init>(Publisher.scala:167)
    at scala.swing.Publisher$$anon$1.<init>(Publisher.scala:34)
    at scala.swing.Publisher$class.$init$(Publisher.scala:34)
    at scala.swing.Window.<init>(Window.scala:25)
    at scala.swing.Frame.<init>(RichWindow.scala:77)
    at scala.swing.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.scala:19)
    at UI.<init>(UI.scala:3)
    at GuiProgramOne$.main(UI.scala:11)
    at GuiProgramOne.main(UI.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableLike$class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at scala.swing.RefSet.<init>(Publisher.scala:167)
    at scala.swing.Publisher$$anon$1.<init>(Publisher.scala:34)
    at scala.swing.Publisher$class.$init$(Publisher.scala:34)
    at scala.swing.Window.<init>(Window.scala:25)
    at scala.swing.Frame.<init>(RichWindow.scala:77)
    at scala.swing.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.scala:19)
    at UI.<init>(UI.scala:3)
    at GuiProgramOne$.main(UI.scala:11)
    at GuiProgramOne.main(UI.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── GUI.class
├── GUI$.class
├── lib
│   └── scala-swing-2.9.1.jar
├── project
│   └── target
│       └── config-classes
│           ...
├── target
│   └── streams
│       ...
└── GUI.scala
```

build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
    )),
    name := "Game of Life",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.1"
    )
  )
```

code: http://otfried.org/scala/index_28.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your scala version is 2.10.5 and hence the scala-swing version should be scala-`swing-2.10.5.jar`. so you should change your build.sbt file as shown below

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVersion.value
    )
```

and you dont need the `scala-swing-2.9.1.jar` in your lib directory since you already declaring the dependency in *build.sbt*. so remove it to avoid any potential collisions between the managed and un-managed dependencies.

Comment: hooray, thank you, that worked!! I actually tried making them both 2.10.6 and it didn't work, but 10.5 works. I don't know why but I'll take it for now. :)